# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted

Tags: c#, outlook

In my project I want to extract the attachment that attached in a msg file. It works when I do testing on the development project, but once i put in the server I am getting this error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted".

Below is my code to extract the msg file.

```
 var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
 MailItem item = (MailItem)outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(file.fullPath, Type.Missing);

 for (int i = 1; i <= item.Attachments.Count; i++)
 {
      FileInfo fzip = null;
      if (Path.GetExtension(item.Attachments[i].FileName).ToLower().EndsWith(".zip"))
      {
           fzip = new FileInfo(SavePath + item.Attachments[i].FileName);
           string attpath = strSavePath + item.Attachments[i].FileName;
           item.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(attpath);
           ..process zip...
       }
```

The error is on second line. Please help...

Comment: This sounds like the message comes from the (t)rusty COM interop. COM is a bit of a predecessor to .NET. While it already implemented some basic ideas, there is still a lot of areas where it works less then optimal. One special thing with the Office Interop is that it does not work from non-interactive sessions. And of coruse requires Office to be installed. This might be the kind of thing you run as a Service (directly or indirectly as part of a Webserver - wich always run in non-interactive sessions as of Vista.

Comment: Which line causes that error?